# Stack Overflow tag-filtered subsites

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, filtering

It would be cool if something like http://nhibernate.stackoverflow.com or http://nhibernate.stackoverflow.com/filtered/nhibernate gave you a filtered version of SO, which only searched questions with the `[nhibernate]` tag, and only allowed you to add questions with the `[nhibernate]` tag.

This would allow project owners to use SO as their knowledge exchange on their projects, and still have the questions enter the main corpus of SO knowledge.

In fact, if you let users them create a subsite entity in SO like

```
subsite : {
    title : 'NHibernate Knowledge Exchange',
    name : 'nhibernate'
    site : 'http://nhforge.org/', //link back to project site
    logo : 'http://nhforge.org/logo.png', 
    tags : 'nhibernate',
    customcss : null,
}
```

people could easily define these things and have a little branding.

EDIT:
Obviously, the point has been missed.  Dev projects typically use a Google group for dealing with questions when a SO-style system would work better.  The user experience of them linking to the currently filtered questions and writing "remember to put the project tag in when you ask a question! ignore any unrelated questions that you happen to browse to once you click off the filter page we linked to!" doesn't really cut it. With sub-sites (or forced filters or whatever you want to call it) they get the advantages of a custom stack exchange site (branding, reduced noise etc.) without needing to isolate their data from the main SO audience.

Comment: What's wrong with the existing solutions (using interesting/ignored tags, use the advanced search)?

Comment: Don't think you guys quite got it...

Comment: Well done mcintyre321, it has now been done with facebook.stackoverflow.com - it sucks when the average crowd doesn't get your idea, just like every great invention was a bad idea at the time.

Comment: Can we get a status-implemented tag on this?

Comment: @OffBySome: This isn't implemented.

Comment: It's `status-completed` now. Nice.

Answer (score 5):

There's already a URL for that.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/nhibernate

You can get to tag search results by putting the tag name in `[]` in the search box.  Such as:  [`[nhibernate]`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/nhibernate)

Comment: hopefully my edit explains why this isn't quite enough

Answer (score 1):

You could always use the [StackOverflow API](https://stackapps.com/) to create something like this. This would let you provide an easy way for people to read common questions related to a technology.

You couldn't isolate posting, but letting people post without looking at the rest of StackOverflow would discourage people from doing things like searching for answers first. They would also have to interact directly with StackOverflow at some point (e.g. creating an account).

Comment: yeah, initially I thought about how you could use the API, but there are some reasons you couldn't implement it properly (readonly for starters) and thought how much better a system it would be as a first class SO feature.

Answer (score 1):

Effectively completed via:

https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/08/facebook-stackoverflow/

Comment: Does "effectively complete" mean that the NHibernate can now contact you about getting nhibernate.stackexchange.com?

Comment: No. It means this is now *technically possible*. We're evaluating how facebook.stackoverflow works for a least 4-6 months first.

Comment: I thought so. I just wanted to be sure.

Comment: Will you change it to rejected if the FB experiment goes south?

Comment: I think status-deferred would actually be a better tag here.

Comment: The answer/status indicate that the functionality IS available, but (2 years later) this answer is still unresolved.  Can you at least post whether the function is available and or will be be in the near future?