# Provide a virtual URL hierarchy for tags

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, tags, stack-exchange, tag-hierarchy

For example, https://stackoverflow.com/git~/latex/ could behave like a virtual SE which covers only questions tagged [tag:git~] and [latex](/questions/tagged/latex). The intersting/ignored part would be ignored for these tags, new questions would already (editable!) contain the tags (wildcards would require some drop-down-menu) by default. The link https://stackoverflow.com/latex/formatting/q/2812892 would be equivalent to [Change paper size in the middle of a latex document?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2812892/change-paper-size-in-the-middle-of-a-latex-document).

The benefit of this is, that all those proposals at Area 51 that are subsets of others, e.g. [jquery](/questions/tagged/jquery) < [SO](http://stackoverflow.com), [StarCraft](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/starcraft) < [ArQAde](http://gaming.stackexchange.com), could have a virtual SE for their specific tag, and still be part of the big, more general site. The virtual SE could even have it's own domain, if desired by its users. And by adding a subtle "generalize this SE" link, the real SE could also be reached.

**edit** Clarification: Yes, one can already use e.g. https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/starcraft-2, but there will always popup a [Starcraft II proposal](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/11697/starcraft-ii). But instead of opening another SE for that, you could just offer a virtual SE based on that tag and both sides (those who want one general site, and those who believe their subject is broad enough on its own) will be happy.

Comment: See also: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/58741/stack-overflow-tag-filtered-subsites

Answer (score 3):

Why don't you just express your query as

[this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/git*+or+latex)

*show me all questions with either tags beginning with 'git' or the tag 'latex'*

Comment: I know about that one, but for the StarCraft example, we shouldn't need a separate SE for that, but those who want one could use the proposed virtual hierarchy on a separate domain and *there* still use the /tagged/zerg etc.

Comment: You could at least wait 5 minutes for an explanation before [status-declining]... *sigh*

Comment: This proposal goes much further: For example - instead of having a linux and an ubuntu page, have stackoverflow.com/linux or /ubuntu respectively. This will (given it's own URL) look like a dedicated page - especially if new questions are tagged accordingly automatically.

Comment: @Ralph: exactly :) Let's see what e.g. the [Starcraft 2](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/11697/starcraft-ii) followers will say as an example...

Comment: Could you at least implement a tag-search-merging as in `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/git~+or+latex/tagged/svn` -> `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/(git~+or+latex)+and+svn` (is bracketing possible anyway?) and `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/git~+or+latex/q/3656351` -> `http://stackoverflow.com/q/3656351`

Comment: [you've done it](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/08/facebook-stackoverflow/)

Comment: @tobias not exactly, since I'm unclear what the exact love connection between git and latex is.

Comment: @Jeff well, to be fair to Tobias, you *did* implement tag sets. `We can now create a mini-site by selecting relevant tags (in this case, anything Facebook related) and grouping together just the content from those tags.` although of course, those tags have something to do with each other, while git and latex don't.

Comment: thanks @Eat. Yes, git+latex was maybe a sub-optimal example, but my feature-request was just the subsite-based-on-tag-sets, right jeff? (I made that example since I use git to version my thesis written with latex...)

Answer (score 0):

This could be integrated into the UI by some kind of "tag locking", i.e. use the same display as when browsing the tagged/tag1+tag2+... site but do not include these tags into the highlighting mechanism, and have a small closed lock symbol next to the tags. Click a lock to remove that tag from the hierarchy. All tags could have a (hover maybe?) open lock to enter the "virtual SE mode", too.

Comment: If someone feels like visualizing that, please feel free to copy-paste my answer to that. I'll award a 50 rep bounty as reward (assuming enough freehand circles are included).