# Retag adobe-dreamweaver as dreamweaver

Tags: support, tags, retag-request, synonym-request

- Five questions tagged [adobe-dreamweaver](/questions/tagged/adobe-dreamweaver) but not [dreamweaver](/questions/tagged/dreamweaver).
- Six questions tagged both [adobe-dreamweaver](/questions/tagged/adobe-dreamweaver) and [dreamweaver](/questions/tagged/dreamweaver).
- Thus there are a total of eleven questions tagged [adobe-dreamweaver](/questions/tagged/adobe-dreamweaver).
- There are four hundred, nine and ninety questions tagged [dreamweaver](/questions/tagged/dreamweaver).

Questions tagged [adobe-dreamweaver](/questions/tagged/adobe-dreamweaver) should be retagged as [dreamweaver](/questions/tagged/dreamweaver) if they're not already and [adobe-dreamweaver](/questions/tagged/adobe-dreamweaver) should be made a synonym of [dreamweaver](/questions/tagged/dreamweaver) (or burninated?).

Comment: Why not just make a regular old synonym? And why prefer `[dreamweaver]` as the master tag over `[adobe-dreamweaver]`?

Comment: @Cody: I'm not sure entirely how the making synonyms works; it may well do all that's required. I've only ever requested burnination, not creation of a synonym. I was suggesting `[dreamweaver]` as the main one purely because it's got lots more already tagged as it. The other way probably makes more sense.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Personally, I would prefer the other way around:

[dreamweaver](/questions/tagged/dreamweaver) -> [adobe-dreamweaver](/questions/tagged/adobe-dreamweaver)

in order to facilitate [searching using a virtual hierarchy](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/63057/provide-a-virtual-url-hierarchy-for-tags)  like [adobe*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/adobe*)

Comment: +1: you're right. I was going on the facts that (a) there are 499 of one and only 11 of the other, (b) `[dreamweaver]`'s tag wiki is much better. But with a synonym and tag wiki copy those wouldn't be a problem anyway. What about the other `[dreamweaver-*]` tags, then? Rename or synonymise them?

Comment: I'd be cool with renaming them -- I see only two using [dreamweaver-](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dreamweaver*), but that might be worth a secondary question.  I'm not sure if the standard operating procedure will evolve to [tag:tags-with-topics-sub-topics-and-sub-sub-topics]....