# How to request a tag-subdomain?

Tags: discussion, tags, stack-exchange, tag-hierarchy

Once upon a time (2010) I suggested to [Provide a virtual URL hierarchy for tags](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/63057/146482), which was originally [declined](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/revisions/63057/2). Then almost one year later (2011) [along came](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/08/facebook-stackoverflow/) http://facebook.stackoverflow.com, which is really just http://stackoverflow.com showing only and requiring [facebook](/questions/tagged/facebook)-ish tags while hiding all other questions. So technically, this is [implemented](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/revisions/63057/4).

However, to my knowledge fb.so is so far the only such subpage. While we shouldn't overdo it, shouldn't we be able to request other such subpages as well where it makes sense? I bet we could help many people with e.g. game specific [arQAde](http://arqade.com) subpages, or other subpages for Area51 proposals that were subsets of other sites but would still benefit from providing their community with a specific subsite.

Comment: Oh yeah, did I mention I'm still hoping for an [implcit tagging hierarchy](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/58073/146482)?

Comment: Not sure how likely that is to happen. It was the result of a unique collaboration between [FB](https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/545/) and [SO](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/08/facebook-stackoverflow/).

Comment: ...and, by most comments I've seen, hasn't been much of a success here. It seems the big winner has been the Facebook devs, who have been able siphon off a lot of questions they had been getting.