# Comments overflowing into sidebar in iOS 7

Tags: bug, status-declined, safari, ios, full-site

Not too much else I can say, here's a screenshot, and a link to where this happens:

[image]

[Here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/63057/provide-a-virtual-url-hierarchy-for-tags) is the page where this happens.

This problem persisted past the beta, so it's time to fix it!

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/71208/188613

Comment: It always seems odd that a site that caters to developers and the tools developers need to use for their craft would explicitly shy away from pre-release browsers that developers need to use and test. I get that you might postpone fixing some things when a tool is really alpha/broken/new, but to have a policy of non-support seems a bit of a mixed message to me.

Comment: @bmike it's not a mixed message, *we do not support beta browsers*, period.  If it's *our* bug, we're happy to fix it, but in the almost every case it's a bug *in that browser* that's fix on their end.  People who use betas opt into bugs, and are often asked to report said bugs to the software creator...that's what should be done.

Comment: @NickCraver I should be clear - I'm just sharing my impression of the message. I very much appreciate the breadth and definitiveness of the site's support for a plethora of browsers. The mixed message seems to be "don't report anything beta" when it should be - awesome, thanks, we will queue this to try and reproduce things once the beta is GM. Rather than status declined - status-non-repro/status-repro and/or status-deferred would be ideal in my eyes.

Answer (score 9):

We don't support beta browsers.  This is a bug *on their side*, one that should be reported to Apple and hopefully fixed before they release iOS 7.  We can't spend time on transient bugs that aren't caused on our end (often without any possible fix even if we *did* spend time on it).

**Betas are buggy**, that's why they're called betas.

Comment: I disagree. Without looking into the bug you *cannot* definitively know that the bug is on their side, and not on yours.

Comment: @RichardJ.RossIII It works in every other browser including Safari on iOS 6.1.3 - I just verified that on 6 desktop browsers and 6 mobile devices.  Which is more likely, your brand new not-yet-out-24-hours software is buggy, or all my tests are lying?

Comment: I'm not denying that it *could* be a browser bug. I'm just saying that blanket statements about it being a browser bug while saying you wont even look into is contradictory.

Comment: @RichardJ.RossIII I did look into it - did you read my above comment?  Give the 99% probability it's on their side, it's not worth my time to attempt a crazy workaround (*if that's even possible*)...we have better things to do.  Let me be clear: ***you opted into bugs with a beta browser***, expect bugs.

Comment: I don't deny what you are saying, just *how* you are saying it in your answer.

Comment: This answer is outdated now that iOS 7 is officially out and this bug remains.

Comment: It is still most likely a bug with the browser and happening on other sites and not just Stack Exchange and something that Apple needs to fix and not Stack Exchange.

Comment: @JoeW unlikely to be fixed though at this point, meaning SE should still look into it, in the name of consistency and usability.

Comment: @RichardJ.RossIII: isn't the problem that iOS 7 is ignoring consistency and usability?

Comment: @RichardJ.RossIII Unlikely to be fixed? What information is there that apple is unlikely to fix the bug? Chances are this bug will cause issues on more sites then Stack Exchange and will get fixed when they get to it in the priority list.

Comment: @RichardJ.RossIII Not only is this a bug with iOS7 and not us, but you're also using the full site on **mobile software**, for which the full site is still not supported, as per [this FAQ](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/56161/which-browsers-are-officially-supported-and-what-else-do-i-need). Only the mobile view is supported for mobile browsers, so any bugs on the full view are extremely unlikely to be fixed.